# black squares on google maps

Tags: java, javascript, css, google-maps

I tried using google maps on my java-spring mvc project. I followed everything on their [tutoial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

I was able to load the maps but there's this black squares appearing on the maps

[image]

here are the codes for my html code on jsp and css:

```
<div id="fieldMonitorContainer">
</div>

#fieldMonitorContainer {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: Which device you are using ? This problem is device-dependend.

Comment: I use the google maps on my web application, and right now i am using mozilla firefox

Comment: try to give the `border:0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in your css. Somewhere in your css you might have a css rule similar to thi:

```
#fieldMonitorContainer div{
    border:1px solid; 
}
```

Or

```
    #fieldMonitorContainer div{
    border:1px solid black; 
    }
```

If you don't, then use this css rule to solve the issue:

```
    #fieldMonitorContainer div{
        border:none; 
    }
```